# How to sort a map on map values

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a java Map

```
   Map<String , String>
```

The map is like following

```
 olah : 3
 vola : 2
 sola : 5
 jingle : 9
```

i want to sort the map on the value string like sort on 3,2,5,9 for example...is there any efficient way possible.

I also want to know what difference it will make if i put a map with same values but
like

```
Map<String , long>
```

Does it improve any performance...?

Comment: See link here...                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: The basic is this: you can't. A map is a map is a map. What you **can** do, however, is to get the values as list and sort that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Something like

```
Map<String , long>
```

is not possible because Java Collections can not store primitive types. If you want to do that, you can use fastutil http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/ or trove http://trove.starlight-systems.com/. Memory consumption will be better, since no Long objects are created.